# Reg.exe Offline registry edit

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, batch-file

Ok I want to edit an offline registry entry from WinPE, if I am booted into the OS (32bit) the reg key is:

```
hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\mountmgr\noautomount
```

So I boot into WinPE and run my batch file to do these commands:
(Tried on 32bit and 64bit)

```
Echo Loading Regestry Hive
reg Load HKLM\temphive H:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM
pause
Echo Import the reg
reg add "HKLM\temphive\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\MountMgr" /v "NoAutoMount" /t REG_SZ /d 0x1
Reg IMPORT z:\Restore\NoAutoMount.reg
regedt32 /s z:\Restore\NoAutoMount.reg /reg:64
Pause
Echo Query the key
reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MountMgr /s
pause
Echo Unload Registry Hive
reg unload HKLM\temphive
```

Registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mountmgr]
"DisplayName"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\drivers\\mountmgr.sys,-100"
"Group"="System Bus Extender"
"ImagePath"=hex(2):53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,\
72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,00,6d,00,6f,00,75,00,6e,00,74,00,6d,\
00,67,00,72,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"Description"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\drivers\\mountmgr.sys,-101"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000003
"Start"=dword:00000000
"Type"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoMount"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mountmgr\Enum]
"0"="Root\\LEGACY_MOUNTMGR\\0000"
"Count"=dword:00000001
"NextInstance"=dword:00000001
```

Now if I boot to the OS and set this registry entry it works, but if I try to update it ofline it does not. I know if I load

```
HKLM\temphive
```

That's what I need to edit right? But if I do then boot into windows the registry key is not there.
What am I doing wrong? and would it be different for 64bit over 32bit?

Answer (score 1):

When you load the `SYSTEM` hive of a foreign installation (using `reg Load HKLM\temphive H:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`), the `CurrentControlSet` subkey can not be modified directly (and should AFAIK not even exist) because when Windows is booted `CurrentControlSet` is created as a link to some other `ControlSet00X` key. ([See on stackoverflow.com: How does CurrentControlSet differ from ControlSet001 and ControlSet002?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291519/2770331))

To modify values in `CurrentControlSet` you need to instead modify these values in the other existing `ControlSet00X` keys (probably `ControlSet001` and maybe `ControlSet002`), so your code should look like this:

```
Echo Loading Regestry Hive
reg Load HKLM\temphive H:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM
pause
Echo Import the reg
reg add "HKLM\temphive\ControlSet001\Services\MountMgr" /v "NoAutoMount" /t REG_SZ /d 0x1
Echo Unload Registry Hive
reg unload HKLM\temphive
```

Also note, that if you load the hive file `\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM` as `HKLM\temphive`, this means that `HKLM\temphive` is the path that under the online system would have been `HKLM\SYSTEM`. Therefore, there should not be an additional `\SYSTEM` after the `HKLM\temphive` (`HKLM\temphive\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MountMgr`). To get a better overview of what's happening, I'd suggest to open `regedit.exe` to graphically see how the hive was loaded.

---

One last note regarding importing of `.reg` files:
I guess, it's obvious by now, but you need to replace every instance of `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` with `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\temphive\ControlSet001` (using e.g. `notepad.exe`) before importing that file.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a hive using `reg load` it loads that file into the key specified on the command line, in this case `HKLM\temphive`.  So you should be adding the key to a descendant of `HKLM\temphive`, such as:

```
Reg ADD HKLM\temphive\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\MountMgr /v NoAutoMount /t REG_SZ /d 0x1
```

And the quote from the relevant help info (`reg load /?`):

> REG LOAD HKLM\TempHive TempHive.hiv
>       Loads the file TempHive.hiv to the Key HKLM\TempHive

Comment: I tried that, did not work. =/