# Windows 10 not respecting NoAutoMount registry key

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, mount, diskpart

So I've found a frustrating issue. In the past (Windows 7) automounting of disk volumes could be disabled through either `diskpart -> automount disable` or `mountvol /N` both of which set the Registry key:

```
HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/mountmgr/NoAutoMount
```

Having done the same in Windows 10 Ent LTSB 2016 (1607), even while the registry key is set, the OS happily proceeds to mount and assign drive letters anyway.

I have made sure to run `diskpart -> automount scrub` as well as `diskpart -> san policy=offlineall` (and checked the relevant registry key) to no avail.

Am I just SOL on this or is there a new 'home' for this setting?

**Edit**
Diskpart output as requested:

```
DISKPART> automount

Automatic mounting of new volumes disabled.

DISKPART>
```

Comment: What build are you using exactly "Windows 10 Enterprise 2016" isn't clear.  I suspect you mean 1607 or 1511 but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @Ramhound LTSB 2016 is based on 1607

Comment: You created a REG_SZ key with a decimal value 1, right?

Comment: I didn't manually create it, diskpart created it initially. Interestingly diskpart created it as a REG_DWORD. I can find some references online to it being a DWORD as well as references for it being a String. I'll try swapping the type.

Comment: [Reg.exe Offline registry edit](https://superuser.com/questions/834864/reg-exe-offline-registry-edit).  Besides that within the diskpark command just type `automount` and supply us the output.  I can't find any reference to `automount purge` for the [diskpart documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753703(v=ws.11).aspx).  inidcates `scrub` might help.  [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749466(v=ws.10).aspx) indicates that there are only 3 values for it also, none of which, appears to be `offlineall`

Comment: @Ramhound my apologies I meant automount scrub. mixed the words in my head. The san policy of `offlineall` corresponds to a key value of `3`, the details for which can be found [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252636%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) I'll update the main post with the output of automount in a second.

Comment: @Ramhound Changed the key to a REG_SZ instead, rebooted, reran `automount scrub` to make sure the entry for the test drive was wiped, and double checked the NoAutoMount key was still there after. Still no luck, the drive was pulled right up and assigned a drive letter still

Comment: @Ramhound per that same link you provided to the previous superuser question, the key is supposed to be a dword `"NoAutoMount"=dword:00000001` changing it back and double checking things for now.